# CLI Ubuntu lock screen after X minutes

Tags: linux, ubuntu, gnome, lock-screen

Is there a way of making Ubuntu (through the command line) to *lock the screen* after X minutes?

I need to do so for example:

- I'm watching a two-hours movie, so I need to make Ubuntu lock the screen that after 123 minutes.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use:

```
gnome-screensaver-command --lock
```

So you could run, for example, `((sleep $[123*60]; gnome-screensaver-command -l)&)` to run `gnome-screensaver-command` after 123 minutes (123*60 seconds).

---

But there is a more convenient way:

1. Set Ubuntu to lock the screen after 5 minutes of inactivity.
2. Configure the movie player to keep the session "active" while the movie is playing. Totem does it automatically; other players usually have some way or other. (The option might be called "inhibit screensaver" or similar.)

Comment: How do you set Ubuntu to lock the screen after 5 minutes of inactivity?

Answer (score 2):

Remember that you can simplify that command. `gnome-screensaver-command --lock` is quite a long command to write, so you can make it easier by creating an alias for it.

Simply run

```
gedit ~/.bashrc
```

Now scroll down to the end of the file and add the following line

```
alias lock='gnome-screensaver-command --lock'
```

After having saved the file, whenever you run the command `lock` it actually executes `gnome-screensaver-command --lock`. Remember that *.bashrc* isn't a file you would normally see in your home folder because it is hidden by default. If you want it to pop into view just browse to your home folder in nautilus and press Ctrl + H.